# Community ads FAQ

Tags: discussion, advertising, community-promotion-ads

Many sites have special threads for community ads. For example, on Travel, we have promoted the Expatriates proposal.

However, on German Language for example, there's no such thread, but there is the [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag, which is red. There's no information in the tag wiki about who can create such a thread. (I suppose the moderator?)

So what's the process for using the community ads? How can one operate them?

Answer (score 10):

The [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) questions are created automatically by the Community user on the meta of every site that qualifies. The problem for [German Language SE](https://german.stackexchange.com/) is that it is still in public beta. Beta sites don't get all the same bells and whistles ad graduated sites, including the Community Ads.

Comment: So, there will be no community ads on beta sites?

Comment: A bit of searching suggests the only time they ever turned them on for a beta site was for Judaism SE, which was basically a way to let them manage something similar to the community bulletin, back before the bulletin existed. So, no, German will need to graduate to get Community Ads turned on.