# What is the way to advertise an area51 proposal in the beta sites?

Tags: discussion, beta-sites, site-promotion

I have got a site in commitment phase on area51 regarding Arts and Crafts:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77518/arts-and-crafts

I wish to advertise it in the beta sites I frequent.
I have seen proposals with 7% commitment being advertised on some beta sites.

How can I go ahead with my proposal advertisement in a beta site when I cannot find any thread w.r.t promotion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 main options:

- you can discuss with your site (on that meta) to start [Community Promotion Ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248214/260841) - if they agree, you can create ads that will be shown on other sites across the network - although I don't think you can choose which sites to show them on, although I may be wrong. Though this is unlikely to happen (see [Shog9's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248214/how-do-we-get-community-promotion-ads-on-beta-sites#comment816265_248216)).
- you could also put the proposal link in your *about me* section on your profile - anyone who visits your profile will then see the ad and possibly will click on it, follow it and propose example questions.
- you could link to the proposal on your beta site's chat - people may be interested and follow it

Those are the main ways to do this, and there aren't really any more real methods.

Answer (score 2):

I figure this happened via [Community Promotion Ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237281/222299). Check the beta(s) you want to advertise on for questions tagged [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) and submit your advertisement in accordance with the rules.

It seems that Community Ads need graduation, though. That may be subject to change with the latest tohubohu around graduation :D